# How to remap device's sensors to touch screen?

Tags: sensors

I want to play Moto Racer on Fpse (psx emulator) with device's sensors.

I installed Tincore but I have no clue on how to remap the sensors to touch the screen.

In my head you had to remap the coordinates to the area of the analog stick on the screen.

Is it even possible to do that with Tincore or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is impossible to remap sensors to touchscreen with tincore, but if anyone is interested, I found a way to remap sensors to analog stick on PC with MotionInJoy and PSXfin to play moto racer.

EPSXE runs fine some games like Gran Turismo 2 and Need for speed III but for Moto Racer the right analog doesn't work.

So PSXfin comes to save the day. Moto Racer works with it, so connect everything and GAME ON!